# What is this dialog about? STOP! You have one(1) copy/paste remaining

Tags: discussion, support, fun, april-fools

> STOP! You have one (1) free copy/paste remaining.
>
> Get unlimited copy/pasting with The Key by Stack Overflow today.

[image]

Have you checked it?

Comment: What? Do you expect to keep copy-pasting for free?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's spam for [The Key](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/). Have you looked at [the calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day) already?

Comment: Why my reputation is increasing when you get upvote?

Comment: @PratikButani If you got 2 reputation, that is probably because you gain 2 reputation from accepting an answer. Otherwise, you shouldn't be gaining any reputation otherwise. If you are actually gaining reputation that isn't the +2 from accepting or from upvotes on your question itself, that is a major bug that needs to be reported.

Comment: yeah, I got other than +2, Let me give you counts. 8 + 8 upvotes in Q/A. so 160 reputations and +2 for accepting this answer. BUT I got till now **2+136+84+10+10=242**

Comment: Score is upvotes - downvotes. I can't see but my guess would be that there were more upvotes than the score and downvotes to bring the score down.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino The 2 rep could also have been gotten from an edit.

Answer (score 8):

Got it!

On clicking **Preorder** Button

[image]

April fool :)

**Stackoverflow helping us every day, Sometimes it deserves to make us fool.**